# Kotlin - How to implement an ItemClickListener for RecyclerVIew

Tags: android, kotlin

Now that google officially support Kotlin as the primary (or soon to be) language in android, I was trying to translate a project of mine. Even though the Android Studio built-in "Translator" works pretty fine, it apparently couldn't translate a `ItemClickListener` for a `RecyclerView`

As an example this is what I have:

In java, I'm using [this class](https://gist.github.com/nesquena/231e356f372f214c4fe6) I found on GitHub to implement it.

This is my Java code:

```
ItemClickSupport.addTo(recyclerView).setOnItemClickListener(new ItemClickSupport.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {
                    ...
            });
```

How do I set an ItemClickListener for a RecyclerView in Kotlin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually just copy paste that Java code into a Kotlin file, and you'll get the Kotlin code that does the same thing, using the built in converter.

(You can also invoke this converter for an entire Java file with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> on Windows, <kbd>^⌥⇧K</kbd> on Mac, or from the menu via Code -> Convert Java File to Kotlin File.)

What it gives you is the following:

```
ItemClickSupport.addTo(recyclerView).setOnItemClickListener { recyclerView, position, v ->
    // ...
}
```

This makes use of [SAM conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions), and is equivalent to this longer, more Java-like form of calling the function:

```
ItemClickSupport.addTo(recyclerView).setOnItemClickListener(
        object : ItemClickSupport.OnItemClickListener {
            override fun onItemClicked(recyclerView: RecyclerView?, position: Int, v: View?) {
                 // ...
            }
        }
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty new to Kotlin and trying to learn it. Your answer helped me a lot. I had to use the longer form, because the short one was saying that it could not infer the parameters type, even though I could specify them easely

Comment: You can give lambda parameters explicit types, like `v: View` and such, if that helps. But in any case, welcome, and enjoy the language! :)